# How to use datepicker in dynamically created jQuery UI dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, dialog

I have trouble to active the datepicker() in a dynamically created jQuery UI dialog():

**index.html**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $loading = $('<img src="./images/loading.gif" alt="loading">');

    $('.page-popup').each(function() {

        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                .append($loading.clone());
        var $link = $(this).one('click', function() {
                $dialog
                        .load($link.attr('href'))
                        .dialog({
                                title: $link.attr('title'),
                                width: 600,
                                height: 300
                        });

                $link.click(function() {                
                        $dialog.dialog('open');

                        return false;
                });

                return false;
        });

    });

    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({         
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"      
    });

});
```

The external page which gets loaded by a link like that:

```html
<a href="input.html" title="Input" class="page-popup">Input</a>
```

it has just a form to select or correct the date:

**input.html**

```
<form method="post" action="?">
    <input type="text" name="date" value="2000-01-01" class="datepicker">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**How can I activate the datepicker for the different dialogs?**

Comment: Instantiate the datepicker on the success of the load() call.

Comment: Thx, basically that would work too, but my mistake was that I reload jquery and jquery-ui on the subpage... That blocked the somehow the datepicker().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the subpage can not reload jquery.js and jquery-ui.js. So here my solution:

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {              
        var $loading = $('<img src="./images/loading.gif" alt="loading">');        
        $('.page-popup').each(function() {                    
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>').append($loading.clone());
            var $link = $(this).one('click', function() {
                    $dialog
                            .load($link.attr('href'))
                            .dialog({
                                    title: $link.attr('title'),
                                    width: 600,
                                    height: 300
                            });        
                    $link.click(function() {                
                            $dialog.dialog('open');        
                            return false;
                    });        
                    return false;
            });                
        });            
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({         
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"      
        });            
    });
    </script>
  </head>
<body>

   <a href="input.html" title="Input" class="page-popup">Input</a>

</body>
</html>
```

**input.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- Don't load jquery and jquery-ui again!!! -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({            
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"      
       });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post" action="?">
        <input type="text" name="date" value="2000-01-01" class="datepicker">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Render the datepicker in the `open` event of the dialog as follows.

```
                   $dialog
                    .load($link.attr('href'))
                    .dialog({
                            title: $link.attr('title'),
                            width: 600,
                            height: 300,
                            open: function(){
                             $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({         
                                     dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"      
                                  });
                             }
                    });
```

Comment: Actually I tried that before and that wasn't the problem. The problem was, that the subpage also loaded the jquery.js and jquery-ui.js somehow that blocked the datepicker.